# What does default do in CHARACTER SET and COLLATE when creating a database?

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
CREATE DATABASE db_name
    [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [[DEFAULT] COLLATE collation_name]
```

The mysql docs tell me that you can optionally specify DEFAULT for these two lines, but what does it actually do?

How is `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET` different from `CHARACTER SET`?
(The same goes for collate)

Comment: MySQL always converts your CREATE DATABASE statement to its inner form - you can see this by execution `SHOW CREATE DATABASE db-name;` while creating the database with different forms of this statement. For mentioned options - DEFAULT will be added to `CHARACTER SET` parameter if it is not specified, and removed from `COLLATE` if it is specified (which is defined by the fact that default collation is a property of the charset).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference. They do the exact same thing, whether you use the `DEFAULT` keyword or not. It's just optional syntax. You would use it only for readability or personal preference.

There are other examples of optional syntax in SQL, for example the `AS` keyword when declaring column aliases or table aliases, or the word `COLUMN` in `ALTER TABLE <name> ADD [COLUMN] <name> ...`

Keep in mind SQL was designed by a committee, so there were bound to be some areas where people disagreed on the syntax, and it was easier to make some syntax optional than to get them to agree. :-)